# Slick slider, padding in the first slide

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

My idea is the following one:
 I would like to put a padding in the first slide from **slick.js**, and yes, i already tried the `:first` element in css.. But what I really wanted is: put an css class in the first ever element **and then** change the class when its not appearing

What I've so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slider1').slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 4
    });

    $('.slider1').on('click', function (event, slick, currentSlide) {
        if (currentSlide === 0) {
            console.log('First element');
            $(this).eq(currentSlide).addClass('first-slide-is-active111');
        } else {
            $(this).eq(currentSlide).removeClass('first-slide-is-active111');
        }
    });
});
```

but doesnt work.. any help?

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tmfvk8hc/)

**edit:** to make me clear what i would like to do is like a netflix slider.. with space in the first slide..

Comment: any error which you would like to focus us on ?

Comment: no error, in the console shows me 'first element' so, it should work.. but doesn't add any class or remove..

Comment: did you try to debug your code ?

Comment: _Note for next time:_ Only add the relevant tags when you post a question

Comment: I already added a jsfiddle ..

Comment: great to have a fiddle

Comment: Css doesn't exist in jsfiddle

Comment: `function (event, slick, currentSlide)` only event is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed your code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slider1').slick({
      dots: false,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 4,
    });

    $('.slide:first').addClass('first-slide-is-active111');

    $('.slider1').on('afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide) {
      if (currentSlide === 0) {
        console.log('First element');
        $('.slide:first').addClass('first-slide-is-active111');
      } else {
        $('.slide:first').removeClass('first-slide-is-active111');
      }
    });
});
```

[js fiddle with fixed code](https://jsfiddle.net/tmfvk8hc/15/)

You had to bind your handler to 'afterChange' not to 'click'. And some logic fixes are aplied too. 
If this logic is not what you want just let me know in comments below and I will try to help.

Comment: You're brilliant bro, but the think is slick.js just adjust the size automatically.. because my idea was like netflix slider.. And i needed padding-left as 100px in the first slider.. but if you put it, slick.js will mess it up... like here: https://jsfiddle.net/tmfvk8hc/20/

Comment: Not sure. It tries to position elements evenly, so maybe it would solve your problem if you played around with setting number of slides to show.

Comment: I opened a new question, can you please take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464133/pure-slider-fix

Comment: @thecreatorasalways   have a look at this [https://jsfiddle.net/tmfvk8hc/23/](https://jsfiddle.net/tmfvk8hc/23/). But it kind of jumps when you move to 1st slide.

Comment: I'll give your answer as correct but could you please help me in my other slider? i think the other one would be better..

Comment: @thecreatorasalways Let me try

Comment: than you so  much

Comment: @thecreatorasalways the other problem seems to have more bugs. I could not do anything sane with it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add class to the first slide and give padding.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.slider1').slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
});


  $('.slider1').on('click', function (event, slick, currentSlide) {
   if (currentSlide === 0) {
       console.log('First element');
         $(this).eq(currentSlide).addClass('first-slide-is-active111');
           } else {
             $(this).eq(currentSlide).removeClass('first-slide-is-active111');
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
.s1 {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider1">

  <div class="s1 slide"><span>Slide1</span></div>
  <div class="slide"><span>Slide2</span></div>
  <div class="slide"><span>Slide3</span></div>
  <div class="slide"><span>Slide4</span></div>
  <div class="slide"><span>Slide5</span></div>
  <div class="slide"><span>Slide6</span></div>

</div>
```

Comment: have you read my question? I already said that i tried the :first element, and what you said its kind of that..